# Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration

The `Configurations` table has primary key `Id` and a foreign key `CurrentVersionId` referencing the `Id` column in the `ConfigurationVersions` table. The `ConfigurationVersions` table has primary key `Id` and a foreign key `ConfigurationId` referencing the `Id` column in the `Configurations` table.

Basically, the main task is how to seed data if tables have references to each others.

I have 2 types of exception. First one concerns `FK_Configurations_ConfigurationVersions_CurrentVersionId` if I call `_context.SaveChanges` after `DeviceConfiguration`, and the other is `FK_Configurations_ConfigurationVersions_configurationId` after adding only after creating versions

> Exception data:
> Severity: ERROR
> SqlState: 23503
> MessageText: insert or update on table "ConfigurationVersions" violates foreign key constraint "FK_ConfigurationVersions_Configurations_ConfigurationId"
> Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
> SchemaName: public
> TableName: ConfigurationVersions
> ConstraintName: FK_ConfigurationVersions_Configurations_ConfigurationId*

Code:

```
[Table("Configurations")]
public class DeviceConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CurrentVersionId { get; set; }
}

[Table("ConfigurationVersions")]
public class DeviceConfigurationVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my migration with creating these tables

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:device_configuration_source", "Versioned,Duplicated,RollBacked,Imported")
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:device_configuration_state", "Published,Draft,Unsaved")
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:device_configuration_type", "Factory,Custom");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Configurations",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                    CurrentVersionId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Configurations", x => x.Id);
                });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ConfigurationVersions",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                    ConfigurationId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ConfigurationVersions", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ConfigurationVersions_Configurations_ConfigurationId",
                        column: x => x.ConfigurationId,
                        principalTable: "Configurations",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
            
     migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Configurations_ConfigurationVersions_CurrentVersionId",
                table: "Configurations",
                column: "CurrentVersionId",
                principalTable: "ConfigurationVersions",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "ConfigurationVersions");
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "Configurations");
}
```

DataSeeder

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DataSeeder(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SeedData()
    {
        if (_context.Configurations != null && _context.Configurations.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            DeviceConfiguration configuration = new()
                  {
                      CurrentVersionId = i
                  };
            _context.Configurations?.Add(configuration);

            DeviceConfigurationVersion version = new()
                  {
                      ConfigurationId = configuration.Id
                  };
            _context.ConfigurationVersions?.Add(version);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            configuration.CurrentVersionId = version.Id;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting an explicit value of `Id` so the `configuration.Id` is equal to `0`

```cs
DeviceConfiguration configuration = new()
{
    CurrentVersionId = i
};
```

Since it's an integer (value type) here you simply copy that `0` to `version.configuration.Id`.

```cs
DeviceConfigurationVersion version = new()
{
    ConfigurationId = configuration.Id
};
```

Only after this line a query is sent to SQL that creates a row, generates and returns back to EF the actual value of the `Id`.

```cs
_context.SaveChanges();
```

So you have two choices

1. Separate it to two calls:

```cs
DeviceConfiguration configuration = new()
{
    CurrentVersionId = i
};

_context.SaveChanges();

// Now the configuration.Id has a non-zero value returned from SQL.

DeviceConfigurationVersion version = new()
{
    ConfigurationId = configuration.Id
};

_context.SaveChanges();
```

2. Simply let EF worry about `Id`s, and operate on objects.

```cs
[Table("Configurations")]
public class DeviceConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DeviceConfigurationVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }
}

[Table("ConfigurationVersions")]
public class DeviceConfigurationVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DeviceConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

[Edit]
I found a second bug. You cannot add a row with foreign key of `0` and that's exactly what are you doing with `DeviceConfiguration`. You can however add a row with foreign key of `null`. Just changing the model this way should fix it.

```cs
[Table("Configurations")]
public class DeviceConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentVersionId { get; set; }
}

[Table("ConfigurationVersions")]
public class DeviceConfigurationVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }
}
```

A remedy of all your problems could be simply [generating IDs in C#](https://www.techyourchance.com/client-generated-ids-vs-server-generated-ids/) and not in the database. This can be very simplified using GUIDs as IDs. (You don't need to check if a GUID is in base since their are "Globally Unique IDs" so no one else in the world will have same GUID as you just generated.) Unfortunately this makes SQL database a little slower.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As i mentioned in the question if I add _context.saveChanges after deviceconfiguration creation I concern exception for this FK
FK_Configurations_ConfigurationVersions_CurrentVersionId. But If i add only context.saves after creation configuration and version then i have exception for configurationId FK.

Comment: I found another problem, and suggested a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Making it optional/nullable in entity and migration is working for me.